# App ID login flow removes ingress service root path after successful login

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, nginx-ingress, ibm-appid

I'm facing the following error while running Node.js WEB app on IBM Cloud Kubernetes with AppId:
The WEB app is accessed via ingress URL: `https://<host url>/ar-studio`

**ar-studio** is the backend service path as is configured in ingress.
index.html has the following HTML line

```
<div class="button"><a id="signin" href="protected/protected.html" title="Sign In to service">Sign In to service</a></div>
```

1. User clicks on the Sign In link and IBM AppId login widget is displayed with the correct redirect uri.
2. User successfully logs in (using cloud directory), and the client page is redirected to     `https://<host url>/protected/protected.html` instead of using the service root path `https://<host url>/ar-studio/protected/protected.html`

How can I fix it so the browser will be redirected to `https://<host url>/ar-studio/protected/protected.html` ?
The app works great without ingress, on my local docker engine.
Here are the relevant ingress yaml fields (some values replaced with `...` for security reasons):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/client-max-body-size: size=400m;
    ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: |
      serviceName=ar-studio rewrite=/;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: "True"
  creationTimestamp: "..."
  generation: 20
  name: ...
  namespace: ...
  resourceVersion: "..."
  selfLink: ...
  uid: ...
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dev.cvar.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ar-studio
          servicePort: http
        path: /ar-studio/
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.cvar.eu-gb.containers.appdomain.cloud
    secretName: ...
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: ...
```

Comment: What is passed in to App ID? What is configured? You need to share more details

Comment: Can you share your ingress manifest?

Comment: Thanks for helping, The original post was updated, ingress config was added.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you'd need to add the bluemix annotation for App ID to your ingress resource, `ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth` - instructions at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress_annotation#appid-auth

Comment: Earlier I tried adding the ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth annotation, and got the same error as described above. Anyway, I prefer not to use appid-auth ingress annotation because I need the same code to run with and without ingress. Therefore using the app-id SDK and not ingress annotation.